# How to programmatically list all apps on Chromebook?

Tags: android, linux, chromebook, chromium-os

I'm looking for a way to programmatically list all apps on a Chromebook. By apps, I mean the Chrome browser itself, additionally installed Chrome apps (like Calculator), Android apps, and Linux apps... as well as any other types of apps that don't fall into these categories. Basically, I want to programmatically mimic the device's own launcher-app-list screen.

There are several apps in the Google Play Store that supposedly list the applications on your device. But they not only fail to list Linux apps (like Android Studio, for example), they don't even list *Chrome browser* as an app.
https://play.google.com/store/search?q=my%20app%20list&hl=en_US

Chrome extensions have a management API that lists Chrome apps, but it doesn't list Android apps or Linux apps (like Android Studio, or Gedit, or the Play Store itself).
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-getAll

Finally, these terminal commands show me Debian packages that were installed, but they miss Android apps and also leave the Chrome browser off the list.

```
dpkq-query --show
dpkg-query --list
apt list --installed
```

So how can I write code in one app that will list ***everything***?

Comment: Most likely, you will need to blend the data from all those sources. I will be somewhat surprised if you can get to some of that from inside an Android app, though.

Comment: @CommonsWare are you suggesting I write three different apps and have them communicate with one another -- perhaps by means of a remote server that they all send data to -- so that at least one of them can have a comprehensive list? How else would I "blend" the datasets?

Comment: "How else would I "blend" the datasets?" -- in developer mode, you can get to a root shell, and that shell I think has `adb` access. With some difficulty, you may be able to write a shell script that gives you a list of launchable Android apps using `adb shell` output. That, combined with the Debian commands, gives you two of your data sources. One imagines that a root shell ought to be able to parse Chrome config files enough for your Chrome extensions analysis. None of this would be easy or particularly user-friendly.

Comment: @CommonsWare so this is not a method of producing an app for public distribution -- it would only work for someone in Chromebook's developer mode, correct?

Comment: Correct. I don't know how a Linux program or shell script could get access to `adb` otherwise. From inside Android, I would not expect you to be able to see Linux or Chrome apps; from inside a Chrome extension, I would not expect you to be able to see Android or Linux apps. A Linux app with sufficient authority might be able to see all three, but I expect that "sufficient authority" requires developer mode.